# Error in compiling file using gcc: "/bin/sh: g++: command not found"

Tags: fedora, compiling, gcc, g++

I want to compile a c++ program in Fedora Linux, but the program isn't compiled correctly. I got the following error:

```
/bin/sh: g++: command not found
make[1]: [*.o] Error 127 
make[1]: Leaving directory
```

Why?

Answer (score 14):

It looks like you need to install g++.  This is available via `dnf`:

```
dnf install gcc-c++
```

In the future, if you see any variant of a `command not found` error, you can search for the package that provides the "command" with

```
dnf whatprovides \*/bin/<command>
```

It used to be that you could just say `whatprovides <command>` but Fedora now wants the full path to the binary that you're looking for. Since we don't know it, we use prepend `\*/bin` to look in all `bin` directories.

---

Note that `dnf` is a replacement for `yum` and became the default package manager in Fedora 22. If you're on an early version of Fedora, you can replace `dnf` with `yum` in any of the previous commands and you'll get the same results.

Comment: You may also want to do `sudo yum group install "Development Tools"`

Answer (score 3):

The C++ compiler, g++, is either not installed or not available via the PATH environment variable.

Try installing the C++ compiler.